# Joomla and cakephp shared login

Tags: cakephp, joomla

I have a joomla instance and a cakephp instance in my site. What I want is to have a single login form for both the joomla and the cake instance.

Is this possible? Possibly there is a plugin that allows this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [Joomla-CakePHP bridge](http://dev.sypad.com/projects/jake/) to execute Cake app in your Joomla instance.

If you want the two to work separately I think you can set up an authentication in Cake to user Joomla database and the data stored there when you are authenticating users.

Comment: i want t owork the mseperately. but should have only single login. ie when i loggd into joomla i should be able to acces the cake instance

Comment: is there anybody have the source of JAKE? i can't download it. all links are dead

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your task using session cookies.
Be aware that Joomla! writes by default session's data in database not in file
[This link](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=1284623) can help you to figure out how to proceed.